# How to use QML Screen Element

Tags: qt, anchor, fullscreen, qml, screen-resolution

I want to use the `screen.height` and `screen.width` property of the QML Screen Element described here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt-components-symbian/qml-screen.html so that I can use anchors in my resizable Qt app.

Strangely I can't find how to use it. Just using `screen.height` or `Screen.height` gives a can't find variable error. In the documentation it says :

> A screen is exposed as a context property named screen. It is not
>   possible to instantiate a Screen object in QML, but the screen must be
>   accessed through the context property.

I think this might explain my question but as I'm new to Qt I don't know what it means. Please if anyone can just help me with my stupid question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have realized that using set fullscreen resizes my root object so after 5 hours rewriting my app to use values relative to the root object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Qt Creator 2.2.1  then use `viewer.showFullScreen();` in **main.cpp**.

In older versions, where **QmlApplicationViewer** is not auto generated I used the following code

```
QDesktopWidget *screen = QApplication::desktop();

QRect rect = screen->screenGeometry(-1);



int screenHeight = rect.height();

int screenWidth = rect.width();



delete screen;



QDeclarativeView *view = new QDeclarativeView;

if(screenHeight > screenWidth)

    view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/StopWatchP.qml"));

else

    view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/StopWatchL.qml"));



QObject *parentObject = qobject_cast<QGraphicsObject *> (view->rootObject());

parentObject->setProperty("width",screenWidth);

parentObject->setProperty("height",screenHeight);
```

where the [QDesktopWidget](http://http//doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdesktopwidget.html) is used to get the screen and its corresponding size.

If the screen height is more, then I will load the QML file designed for Portrait mode else the Landscape mode.